# Cascade delete on one to many relation with same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a Comment entity where a new comment has no parent but a list of Replies which is also a Comment with Required Parent.

A user can create a comment then other user can reply to that comment which will be parent of all these replies and replies can also have further replies with a parent comment for every reply.

How do I cascade delete the replies of each comment so that all the replies and their further replies are deleted automatically when I delete a comment or reply of that comment.

**Here is the Comment Model:**

```
public class Comment
{
    public Comment()
    {
        Replies = new List<Comment>();
    }
    [Required]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }      
    [Required]
    public string Audio { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Comment> Replies { get; set; }

    public Comment Parent { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is What I tried with Fluent API**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().
            HasMany(s => s.Replies).
            WithRequired(s => s.Parent).
            WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

**It throws following errors**

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Comments_Parent_CommentId' on table 'Comments'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

Comment: I don't think you can have on cascade delete with a required parent. Try specifying it as optional.

Comment: Still does't work
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().
                HasMany(s => s.Replies).
                WithOptional(s => s.Parent).
                WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Comment: Well, then you might need to remove cascade deletion and delete replies manually.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change to SQL table like

> ALTER TABLE Comment ADD CONSTRAINT
>   FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Comments_Parent_CommentId FOREIGN KEY (CommentId)
>   REFERENCES T1 (CommentId)
>   **ON DELETE CASCADE;**

The last bold part is the key.

Comment: How can i do this using Fluent API?